# Integrate Node.JS + Hadoop + Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, hadoop, cassandra, bigdata

I'm testing Node.JS + Cassandra.
Now I want to integrate Hadoop (or any other) to query and analyse my data.
I can't find info about using Node.JS with Hadoop.
Is there some driver or library?
Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific and detailed question for this question to be "on topic" for StackOverflow.  As it stands now, it is far too broad.